# Creating a callback for set_error_handler in Phil Sturgeon's REST controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using Phil Sturgeon's REST_Controller in CodeIgniter, but I would like to use try...catch blocks in a way more familiar to an old Java programmer like myself. So, I added a function to Phil's controller:

```
    function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext){
        $ee = new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline, $previous);
        throw $ee;
    }
```

Then in the `__construct` method of the controller, I tried to connect that function up with error handling:

```
    set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");
```

When I now run a controller that extends REST_Controller, I get this error message:

> set_error_handler() expects the argument (exception_error_handler) to
>   be a valid callback

If I put the function and the call set_error_handler in the sub-class, there is no error and my try...catch blocks catch the exception whenever there is an error. Why isn't my callback valid in the super class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm grateful to user3345621 for pointing me in the right direction. I scrolled down the PHP manual entry for [set_error_handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) to the comments and found a great piece of advice about 3 ways of setting a callback function.

In REST_Controller, I added the `exception_error_handler` function as mentioned in my original question, except that I made it static as recommended by user 3345621.

```
protected static function exception_error_handler($errno, 
                                                  $errstr, 
                                                  $errfile, 
                                                  $errline, 
                                                  $errcontext){
        $ee = new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline, $previous);
        throw $ee;
    }
```

I then noticed the `early_checks` method in the REST_Controller. I added the following call to set_error_handler in the `early_checks` method:

```
set_error_handler(array(&$this, 'exception_error_handler'));
```

The comment in the PHP manual says that ampersand is important.

Now when an error occurs in a sub-class, an ErrorException is thrown as I require.

Answer (score 3):

Your child class is inheriting your parent's constructor.

`set_error_handler(array($this, 'exception_error_handler'));`

**EDIT**

After setting:

```
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext){
        $ee = new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline, $previous);
        throw $ee;
    }
```

TO:

```
protected static function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext){
        $ee = new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline, $previous);
        throw $ee;
    }
```

You should be able to call it as follows:

```
__construct(){
set_error_handler(function(){self::exception_error_handler("exception_error_han‌​dler")});
}
```

Comment: When I put that line in the parent's constructor, it just causes a 500 Internal Server Error. Do you mean I should put that in the child constructor? What I want is to set this up in one place and then all child classes have access to the same functionality.

Comment: Hmmm. Curiouser and curiouser. When I put that line in the child's constructor, everything works. I've read the incredibly confusing PHP docs. How did you work that out from them? I still want to be able to set the error handler more globally in the parent, though.

Comment: hmmm, try:" set_error_handler(function(){self::customErrorHandler();}); " - And put it in the parent consturctor

Comment: Sorry also wanted to add, you should make the "customErrorHandler()" function static on the parent's side.

Comment: Sorry, copied some old code over without editing. Here's what I wanted to post. Try: "set_error_handler(function(){self::exception_error_handler("exception_error_handler")});"

Comment: No sorry. I tried various combinations of your suggestion but they all cause a 500 internal server error. It's past midnight here so got to go for now. Thanks for the help. Up 1 for pointing in what feels like the right direction.

Comment: I'm afraid {self::exception_error_handler("exception_error_han‌​dler")}); displays an error in Netbeans and see previous comment.

Comment: It's strange that you should get an 500 error from the server without any PHP Output. Check if you have error reporting turned on: http://www.php.net/function.error_reporting.

Also, are you sure "ErrorException" receives the correct arguments from "exception_error_handler"